# How to save text string of Hex without Python type conversion, i.e. just as plain text

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, hex

Python 3.6, Sqlite3.

I have some code which accepts user input, and stores it as a variable called uinput. I have confirmed this is saved as type Str by Python.

```
uinput = input ("enter the string: ")
print("Type of uinput is:",type(uinput))
```

gives the output

```
Type of uinput is: <class 'str'>
```

uinput will always be of the format 0x then 40 characters, or just the 40 characters (I have some other logic that verifies this before attempting the DB update - this bit is working).

My testing so far has been using the 0x then 40 characters format, eg 
    0x689C56AEf474Df92D44A1B70850f808488F9769D

I am aware I can do the following to remove the 0x prefix, so the DB UPDATE is a consistent style
    if uinput.startswith(("0X", "0x")):
        uinput=uinput[2:]

However when I try to write this to my Sqlite db the script freezes, which I believe is because Python is converting the Hex to another format, instead of passing it as a string.

```
#conn2 declared earlier, and is available to this function
cur = conn2.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE db1 SET myhex=? WHERE ID=123", (uinput))
conn2.commit()
```

If i go into sqlite3 on the command line and try the UPDATE command manually, I get the following error:
    Error: hex literal too big: 0x689C56AEf474Df92D44A1B70850f808488F9769D

- This is why I think Python is doing some sort of type conversion.

All i want to do is store it as a string, just like the print(uinput) command shows (I guess that does its own type conversion in the background though!)...
eg "0x689C56AEf474Df92D44A1B70850f808488F9769D" or "689C56AEf474Df92D44A1B70850f808488F9769C", either is fine.

It needs to be in this format as the DB is human readable (via a csv export) so I don't want to have to convert it back again to get the ascii that was originally submitted by the user)

I'm sure it will be something simple but i've spent nearly 2 hours on just this issue and i'm running out of ideas!

Thanks

Comment: SQLite only handles integers up to 64 bit, which translates to a max 8 hex digits after a `0x` in a literal. What affinity is your myhex column? It's really hard to help with sql questions without seeing your table schemas.

Comment: Er, 16 digits. Doh.

Comment: myhex column was created as type Str in sqlite

Comment: That error message cannot happen with the string you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Having slept on it and approached it with a fresh brain today, i've found a solution that seems to work.

```
cur = conn2.cursor()
sql_query= "UPDATE db1 SET myhex=? WHERE ID=123"
cur.execute(sql_query, (str(uinput))
conn2.commit()
```

...basically forcing the variable to be a string during the execute.

I had tried a variation of this previously, and guess there must be a subtle difference in how it is parsed.

```
cur.execute("UPDATE db1 SET myhex=? WHERE ID=123", (str(uinput)))
```

^^^this did not work

Comment: The first block is not valid Python code (at least one parenthesis is missing, and even then it will break).